# capture the logcat output during the android junit test execution

Tags: java, android, junit, adb, android-testing

I was able to capture the logcat output using below java code in android.

```
public void WriteLogCatOutput() {

    StringBuilder log;
    log=new StringBuilder();
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));


        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            log.append(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

I can keep reading the logs, just by removing the "-d" flag in code above and placing it in a thread.

But is that possible to read the logcat outputs  just with TWO calls/one call to the above method, so that we can capture the logcat output from the start of my JUnitTest and towards the end of JUnit Test and get only the logcat output in between?